# Is there another way to replace values like zero and one with NaNs?

Tags: python, data-science, feature-engineering

i'm trying to replace integer values like -1 and 0 with NaN values. Here is the code:

```
df = df.replace(0, np.nan)
df = df.replace(-1, np.nan)
```

However the dataframe is large:

```
 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
 RangeIndex: 891221 entries, 0 to 891220
 Columns: 366 entries, LNR to ALTERSKATEGORIE_GROB
 dtypes: float64(267), int64(93), object(6)
 memory usage: 2.4+ GB
```

and it takes a lot of time when i run it.

Is there any faster alternative to this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are recreating the dataframe, and assigning `df` to a new object, *and you are doing that twice!* Why not do the replace in-line like this?

```py
df.replace([0,-1], np.nan, inplace=True)
```

`inplace` is, by default, `False`. For more info and examples on `replace`, check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html).

[Here](https://repl.it/repls/SimplisticScaryKnowledge) is a skeleton code that shows that you achieve a *speedup factor of almost 2* doing it this way compared to the way you were.

Comment: Yes it is much better.